# i do not know why table head is located the table body

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

table head coming over table body in ejs file like that
[image: table head coming over table body]
the code is:

```html
<div class="container">
            <% for(var i = 0; i < user_show_cart.products.length; i++) { %>
            <td><%= i + 1 %></td>
            <form class="form" method="" action=""  id="">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                        <tr>                  
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Img</th>
                            <th>Size</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="<%= user_show_cart.products[i].productId %>"><!--do not put td not to make displacement-->
                            <input type="text" name="productTitle" value="<%= user_show_cart.products[i].title %>">
                            <input type="text" name="productImg" value="<%= user_show_cart.products[i].img %>">
                            <input type="text" name="productSize" value="<%= user_show_cart.products[i].size %>">
                        </tr>       
                    </tbody>
                </table>       
                <table class="table">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                        <tr>                  
                            <th>Color</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                            <th>SubTotalPric</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>    
                            <input type="text" name="productColor" value="<%= user_show_cart.products[i].color %>">
                            <input type="number" name="productPrice" value="<%= user_show_cart.products[i].price %>">
                            <input type="number" name="productQuantity" value="<%= user_show_cart.products[i].quantity %>" min="1" max="1000" step="1"></td>
                            <input type="text" name="productSubTotalPrice" value="<%= user_show_cart.products[i].subTotalPrice %>">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn text-dark update" >Change Quantity</button>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
            <% } %> 
        </div>
```

i try to make the table with the normal case , where head over body
i tried to divide the table into 2 parts to overcome this problem, but not succeed.

Comment: You forgot the <td> inside the <tr>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tbody` rows do not include the necessary `<td>` elements.

Without the `td`'s:

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>                  
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Img</th>
            <th>Size</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <input type="text" name="productTitle" value="Title">
            <input type="text" name="productImg" value="Image">
            <input type="text" name="productSize" value="Size">
        </tr>       
    </tbody>
</table>
```

With `td`'s:

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>                  
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Img</th>
            <th>Size</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="productTitle" value="Title"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="productImg" value="Image"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="productSize" value="Size"></td>
        </tr>       
    </tbody>
</table>
```